# Analytics Regex: eclude part of links which contain the one word

Tags: regex, google-analytics

please help me to nake regular expresion.
I have two types of links:

1) collection page:https://www.rentuu.com/collections/bedroom

2) product page:https://www.rentuu.com/collections/bedroom/products/bean-bag

They have the same begining and I need to see in my report only collection pages and exclude product pages.

How can I change `*collections/.*` to make it?

Comment: Try `^collections/[^/]*$`

Comment: Wiktor, it doen't work at all showing no pages.

Comment: And if you replace `^` (start of string) with `(^|/)` (start of string or slash)?

Comment: Why you don't use "exclude" filter? and regexp like this `\/products\/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, your rule for such URLs would be to check URLs with "collections", but without "products".

There's a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) discussing regex for excluding string pattern. However, I think it's not supported in Google Analytics.

One approach would be two use two filters in your reports: one to include all pages with "collections", an other one to exclude pages with "products". You can of course bee more specic with the rules. E.g.
[image]

If for any reason you must use only one filter, you could craft something like this, meaning: get all pages starting with /collections, having some other letters (collection name) after an other / character, which is then followed by URL parameters (?) or end of string ($), meaning no product names can come after.

```
^\/collections\/[a-z]+(\?|$)
```

Comment: Hi, your expression works perfectly.
Thank you fot it.